# Showing text inside of a image

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, stylesheet

How can I add inside my PNG image the unread message count in text? The image can be viewed at http://s11.postimg.org/6niiwdakv/login_icon6.png

header:

```
        span Messages
        =image_tag "login_icon6.png", class: 'img4'
```

Unread count code:

```
= current_user.mailbox.inbox(:unread => true).count
```

Comment: set the image as a background image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a tag with an id for the unread count and then set the background image of that tag to be your image. 
I don't remember HAML syntax but something like:

```
#count=current_user.mailbox.inbox(:unread => true).count
```

and in your css

```
#count {
    background-image: /dir/img.png
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not show the blue circle background image. It is only outputting the unread count. When inspecting the page I don't see the background image getting called on so the CSS must not be setup right. Here is the default css for my app. https://gist.github.com/pwz2k/64bf7640688e4e97a9f2